# json data is not pulling into highcharts

Tags: php, ajax, json, highcharts

i have an issue with JSON and highchart: I am fetching data from php mysql using ajax and getting response but problem is i am not able to put the data into highchart series. Can anyone help me on the issue i am totally new to highcharts. My moto is to show data monthly income into chart according to months fetched from mysql table.

I am geting below JSON from ajax call on chart_income.php file. See PHP code.

**JSON :**

```
[{"month":"1","total":"4500"},{"month":"2","total":"20"},{"month":"3","total":"8300"}]
```

Here is jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function requestData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax/chart_income.php',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                chart.series[0].setData(data.month);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    };


    var chart;
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'demo_chart',
            type: 'line',
            events: {
                load: requestData
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'INR'
            }
        },
        series: [{
                //name: 'Random data',
                data: []
            }
        ]
    });

});
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$total_yearly_income = $db->query("SELECT MONTH(income_date) as month_updated, COUNT(income_date) as month_updates, SUM(income_amount) as month_total FROM mt_income WHERE income_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-03-23 23:59:59' GROUP BY MONTH(income_date)");
$i=0;
if ($total_yearly_income) {
    if ($db->num_rows($total_yearly_income)) {
        while ($res = $db->fetch_array($total_yearly_income)) {
            $month = $res["month_updated"];
            $total = $res["month_total"];
            $array[] = array("month" =>$month,"total"=>$total);
        }
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: What do you get when you do `alert(data.month)`? Maybe your `data` is a string, not a JS array.

Comment: JSON data mention in post.

Comment: So what do you get from the alert? (`alert(data.month)`)

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts expects the data to specify x,y values. There are two ways to do this:

```
var data = [[1,4500],[2,20]
```

or

```
var data = [{x:1,y:4500},{x:2,y:20}]
```

Once you have data is this format (either from the php, or by processing the returned data into the correct format), you call:

```
chart.series[0].setData(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your number data should have number type, instead of string. To achieve this you can set it in your PHP and generate JSON in this figure:

[{"month":1,"total":4500}]

or use parseFloat() function to replace string value with number and then use correct JSON in setData();

I advice also to suggest with article about preprocessing data: 
http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing